# HTML5 "Press ESC to exit fullscreen" custom message

Tags: html, audio, video, fullscreen

I'm trying to localize the "Press Esc to exit fullscreen" message when you enter fullscreen for `<video>`. Is it possible to control/modify that message?

I've tried changing the browser language preference to a different language to see if it detects it but that did not work.

I also attempted to pass a srclang flag to the `<source>` tag... unsuccessful

Comment: Does the browser not automatically handle the user's preferred language for those types of message? I am a native English speaker so I don't know how that works, but I would imagine that most browsers are configured to show messaging in the native language

Comment: No I tried changing the preferred language on my browser. The text on the page changes but not that message. It's still in english.